# Executing a batch update in hibernate at a faster speed using mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am carrying an update to a table with 5 columns having blob property in Mysql which has images stored in it. My problem is that it take a longer time to do a simple update.What could be causing the slowness in my database table because even when i try to update the records from mysql command line its also slow. I am using hibernate to perform the update here is my code.

```
  public  void update(String ac,String balance) {
        Session s=CFactory.getSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        try {
          Query qry=s.createQuery("from Accounts where acNumber='"+ac+"'");
          Accounts acc=(Accounts )qry.uniqueResult();
          acc.setBalance(balance);
          s.update(acc);
          s.getTransaction().commit();
          System.out.println("update ok");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I improve the speed at which the table get updated because I have over 1000 records that i need to update as a batch.

Comment: I don't think slow query and hibernate has any relationship in this case. May the content that you are storing in DB is large so that it is taking time to write in DB.

Comment: @Amogh what can i do to improve my DB query speed that is mysql because am storing images